# How to make the effect on the edge of the facial mask?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

how to make the effect on the edge? I have made the model, but struggling on the textures. Thanks for you time. :D

[image][image]

Comment: Do you want actual geometry there or can it be by the means of a bump texture on that area ?

Comment: Which would be the more efficient way? I think the actual geometry would be great, isn't it increasing a lot of time on rendering?